# Set-Cookie then redirect working under perl CGI, but not mod_perl

Tags: perl, cgi, mod-perl2

I've got a funny problem with setting a cookie and then redirecting under mod_perl. I've had a regular cgi environment up until now, and the set cookie/redirect has never been an issue; everything has worked as expected. When I turned on mod_perl however, I get a status 200 and an html body being sent with the redirect url in it. The cookie is always being placed after the header and before the document body, even though I'm printing it before the redirect. I trimmed down the script to bare-bones so you can see what I mean:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $cookie = CGI::cookie(
  '-name'     => 'joe',
  '-value'    => 'fred',
  '-path'     => '/cgi-bin',
  '-httponly' => 1,
);
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie\n";

print $cgi->redirect(-uri => 'http://example.com/cgi-bin/joe.cgi', -status => 303);
```

When I test this with curl under regular CGI, I get (domain name replaced and snipped for brevity):

```
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2012 16:26:55 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< Set-Cookie: joe=fred; path=/cgi-bin; HttpOnly
< Location: http://example.com/cgi-bin/joe.cgi
< Content-Length: 0
```

...which is what I expect. When I test this under mod_perl, I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2012 16:26:38 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
< Location: http://example.com/cgi-bin/joe.cgi
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
Set-Cookie: joe=fred; path=/cgi-bin; HttpOnly
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>200 OK</title>
</head><body>
<h1>OK</h1>
<p>The answer to your request is located <a href="http://example.com/cgi-bin/joe.cgi">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I'm getting no warnings in logs. Any idea why mod_perl has decided to handle this redirect in such a bizarre way?

Comment: mod_perl/2.0.5, Apache/2.2.22

Comment: *How* are you running this under mod_perl? Are you using ModPerl::Registry or running a handler directly?

Comment: Have you seen this page about cookies/redirect? http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/coding/cooking.html#Sending_Cookies_in_REDIRECT_Response__ModPerl__Registry_  shows multiple ways of cookie/redirect, based on your style of implementation.

Comment: @friedo, looks like ModPerl::Registry. That's what I have in my apache config. Apologies, I've only just started running mod_perl.

Comment: @mrk, I will do some testing with this, but I've always read that you can in most cases drop in your cgi scripts under mod_perl and they will just work provided you aren't doing anything too wierd. I wanted to keep the scripts from using mod_perl specific coding, at least for a while, so I can switch back and forth.

Comment: So it looks like if I just process cookies with:
  $r->err_headers_out->add('Set-Cookie' => $cookie);
then everything works. mrk, if you want to answer this I can credit you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually fixed everything for me was using:

```
my $r = Apache2::RequestUtil->request;
$r->err_headers_out->add('Set-Cookie' => $cookie);
```

...for my cookie processing. This ensures cookies will work if you decide to redirect later.

I was trying to avoid polluting my pure cgi scripts with mod_perl so I could switch back and forth, but compromised with this. All other header processing works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC its explained in [CGI to mod_perl Porting. mod_perl Coding guidelines](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/porting.html)

Basically, it will work as you expect if you use `$cgi->redirect( -cookie => $cookie, ... )`
Mixing `$cgi->header` and print "header\n" tends no to work reliably under mod_perl, pick one or the other

Comment: Thanks, but since I happen to process any cookies ahead of the redirect, I would have to do some fancy redesign to combine the cookies with the redirect request. To me cookies have nothing to do with redirects anyway.